# Delete files permanently in Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I have Mac Sierra, I would like to know how to delete files permanently. What should I do? I have
gone through different columns or suggestions; like using the command `- sudo RM -R`; but I'm not sure if that works with Mac Sierra.

Comment: Why do you say you've seen suggestions like `rm -r` but aren't sure if that works. Have you tried it?

Comment: How permanent is permanent? Throw it in the trash, empty the trash. If it's an SSD that's as good as gone forever, irretrievably.

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -rf some_dir
```

-r "recursive"

-f "force" (suppress confirmation messages)

**Alternatively**, Navigate to directory (which needs to be deleted) and run this command:

```
rm -rf *
```

Would remove everything (folders & files) in the current directory.

**But be careful**! Only execute this command if you are absolutely sure, that you are in the right directory.

If you want to **Skip trash** then there are two possible ways: (I am aware of)

- **Select** File/Folder in Finder
- **Click** on File Menu while pressing **Option** button
- Select **Delete Immediately**
- Confirmation Box will open, click **OK** to delete and complete request

**SHORT WAY** `Option + Command + Delete` and Click **OK** to confirm

Lastly, it can be achieved by **writing an Automator Script**.